# ClassNotFound Exception : Maven in Eclipse is not working

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e

I have following pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>my.org</groupId>
    <artifactId>project</artifactId>
    <packaging>${packaging.type}</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>My Project Name</name>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <properties>
                <packaging.type>war</packaging.type>
                <outputFileNameMapping>@{artifactId}@.@{extension}@</outputFileNameMapping>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>uat</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <packaging.type>jar</packaging.type>
                <outputFileNameMapping>@{artifactId}@.@{extension}@.@{version}@</outputFileNameMapping>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <build>
        <finalName>My Project Name</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <outputFileNameMapping>${outputFileNameMapping}</outputFileNameMapping>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestFile>src/main/webapp/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I am getting error like `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`

I am guessing my project in Eclipse is not loading any Maven dependencies at all.

If I run same project from command line then its working.

But if I removed following line then it works perfectly in Eclipse.

```
<outputFileNameMapping>${outputFileNameMapping}</outputFileNameMapping>
```

Can anyone help here ?

My Eclipse version

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)
Build id: 20150219-0600

EDIT: Adding stacktrack

```
Apr 25, 2017 12:38:35 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:edte' did not find a matching property.
Apr 25, 2017 12:38:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.64
Apr 25, 2017 12:38:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Aug 19 2015 17:18:06 UTC
Apr 25, 2017 12:38:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         7.0.64.0
Apr 25, 2017 12:38:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Linux
Apr 25, 2017 12:38:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            4.8.10-040810-generic
Apr 25, 2017 12:38:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Apr 25, 2017 12:38:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
Apr 25, 2017 12:38:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_121-8u121-b13-0ubuntu1.16.04.2-b13
Apr 25, 2017 12:38:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Apr 25, 2017 12:38:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         /var/tmp/projects/edte/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
Apr 25, 2017 12:38:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         /home/bhushanp/workspace/apache-tomcat-7.0.64
Apr 25, 2017 12:38:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,suspend=y,address=localhost:35365
Apr 25, 2017 12:38:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/var/tmp/projects/edte/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
Apr 25, 2017 12:38:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/home/bhushanp/workspace/apache-tomcat-7.0.64
Apr 25, 2017 12:38:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=/var/tmp/projects/edte/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps
Apr 25, 2017 12:38:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/home/bhushanp/workspace/apache-tomcat-7.0.64/endorsed
Apr 25, 2017 12:38:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Apr 25, 2017 12:38:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib
Apr 25, 2017 12:38:35 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8330"]
Apr 25, 2017 12:38:35 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8339"]
Apr 25, 2017 12:38:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 968 ms
Apr 25, 2017 12:38:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Apr 25, 2017 12:38:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.64
Apr 25, 2017 12:38:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Apr 25, 2017 12:38:37 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Apr 25, 2017 12:38:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.HttpSessionListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.HttpSessionListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1858)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1709)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:488)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4919)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5517)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1574)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Apr 25, 2017 12:38:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
Apr 25, 2017 12:38:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
Apr 25, 2017 12:38:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/edte] startup failed due to previous errors
Apr 25, 2017 12:38:37 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8330"]
Apr 25, 2017 12:38:37 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8339"]
Apr 25, 2017 12:38:37 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1814 ms
```

Also, I have already added dependency for class 'org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.HttpSessionListener', still it is giving me this error.

My [pom.xml](https://pastebin.com/8J5zjxZF)

Comment: Please add the complete stacktrace. You have not added any dependency!

Comment: Do you specified 'outputFileNameMapping' variable in your pom.xml ?

Comment: error like java.lang.ClassNotFoundException? This isn't the place to leave out specifics.

Comment: Add the maven installation in "Eclipse Preferences --> Maven --> Installations" and also specify the settings.xml file in "Maven --> User Settings". If it works from command line, it should work with Eclipse as well with the same maven installation

Comment: I recommend to take a look here: https://github.com/khmarbaise/multienv-maven-plugin

Comment: I have updated the question by adding stackstrace. Also, I have posted content of my pom.xml to https://pastebin.com/8J5zjxZF (As it is huge, I couldn't paste it here)

Answer (score 0):

try to compile your code from command prompt, if you get the same error that mean, dependency is missing. If it works fine, you need to execute mvn eclipse:eclipse, and refresh your project

Comment: Do not use eclipse:eclipse.  Use the m2e plugin instead!